# how to make a selected button for dynamically changing pages using hash

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, hash

I am making dynamically changing pages without a reload of the page.

Currently I have it set up so that it adds a # at the end of the url and then the page name.

for example; mypage.com/index.php#myview.php

I have made it so that it grabs the content for a certain div and replaces the content in the existing page.

The navigation buttons are using a href="myview.php" to navigate but what I want to do next is have the button that links each content to have a selected state. The only problem is I cannot figure out how to tell the buttons to be selected when the href matches the end of the content after hash in the url.

```
$('.boo').delegate("a", "click", function() {

    var newhash  =  "";

    window.location.hash = $(this).attr("href");        
    return false;
});

$(window).bind('hashchange', function() {

    newhash = window.location.hash.substring(1);
    console.log(newhash);

    $(".inner-content").load(newhash + " .control-faders-wrapper");

    if(newhash) {
        alert(newhash)
        $('.boo a').removeClass('selected');
        $('.boo a[href="+newhash+"]').addClass('selected');
    }
});
```

The if (newhash) code was an attempt at creating what I need to do but it just doesn't work and I don't now where to go from there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it should be:

```
$('.boo a[href="' + newhash + '"]').addClass('selected');
```

Right now you are trying to match `a` tags with literally `href="+newhash+"`.

Comment: oh that is perfect and makes sense looking at it now! I just couldn't figure out why it wasn't taking the value from newhash. I always get tripped up by the quotation marks!